# Number of zeros of $z^4-z^3-4z+1$ in the ring $\{ 1 < |z| < 2 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

I need to prove that the number of zeros of $z^4-z^3-4z+1$ in the ring $\{ 1 < |z| < 2 \}$ is equal to $3$.

What I have done so far; I've proved there is only one zero in the $\{|z|\leq1\}$. So the only thing remaining is to prove there is no zeros in the 
$\{|z|\geq2\}$. This part, however, creates a lot of issues for me. I've tried the classic way using Rouche's theorem and even adding new polynomials in order to use it, but nothing helped.

Also tried assuming $z^4-z^3-4z+1=0$ and $|z|\geq2$ with some clever use of inequalites, that didn't help either. I don't know if I'm missing something, but according to WA, one zero is $\approx1.9325$ so that might be causing troubles in my opinion.

Comment: Use Ferrari method

Comment: @learningstudent I'm not familiar with Ferrari method at all. But I will look it up for sure, thanks.

Comment: @learningstudent Did you try it yourself?

Comment: I suspect that there is something wrong with this problem. It doesn't seem to have a simple answer using standard Complex Analysis methods.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That was one of the tasks on the exam in my complex analysis class back in 2015. I seriously don't know what is going on, but I believe they would fix it in their papers since it is published online, visible for all the students.

Comment: @Elsa Can't you ask to whoever made this exam how to solve this question?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That was my plan B after posting here in case noone knows. I will definitely ask now, no doubt.

Comment: @Elsa Then please post here whatever answer you get.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos How did you miss this , I wonder haha

Comment: Aren't you going to share your knowledge with us?

Comment: Azlif solved it

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I will post the original answer if I get it and if it is different from Azlif's solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be proved by Rouche's theorem.

**Hint:** $$|z^4 + 1| > |-z^3 - 4z|$$
on $|z| = 2$.

You can't prove this inequality by just using triangle inequality.

One way to prove the inequality is by letting $z = 2e^{i\theta}$ then the problem is equivalent with $$257 + 32 \cos 4\theta > 256 \cos^2 \theta$$

You can prove that this is indeed true for all $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: What made you think this inequality would work at all ? Did you have any intuition or you got just straight digging and whatever happens ?